# Rails app performance decrease due to associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, associations

My current Rails 3 app has seen a performance decrease as I introduce more associations to the schema.

This performance is not related to page loads, but to a background task that I run using resque. The task parses an external data source to populate the database. It does this through a custom helper method (quite a long one).

I don't expect the task to execute very quickly, because it is parsing a lot of data, but recently after adding a few additional associations, I have seen the execution time for my test method increase from 2 minutes to about 5 minutes. I'm running on a VM, so perhaps that's why it is so slow in general.

Using ruby-prof, it seems that the bulk of the additional computation is spent in methods dealing with the associations I added:

```
ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionAssociation#* (where * is any number of methods)
```

When I have added associations, I have included indexes on the association table. However, other than this, I'm not sure what, if anything, I can do to mitigate the performance hit I'm seeing from adding these associations.

So my questions are:

1) Is it possible that adding associations can cause such drastic performance decrease in a Rails app?
2) What are the best practices for having a Rails app with many associations that performs well?

EDIT: Some additional info as requested

- database: Postgres
- the associations I added were both HABTM
- it is the populating of these associations that takes up the time. I am creating hundreds, if not thousands of associations during the population process. For bulk inserts, I have been using activerecord-import, which speeds things up significantly, but I am not aware of an equivalent for associations.
- I was doing the following (variables changed for simplicity):

  ```
  // flavors_array is an array of all the Flavor objects I want to associate with my ice_cream
  ice_cream.flavors = flavors_array
  ```
- I did it this way because I know with certainty that there are no preexisting associations for this 'ice_cream' instance that I would be deleting by using '='
- However, this method is still very slow
- **IMPORTANT:** When I replace the above with a SQL statement to bulk insert the associations directly into the association table (via IDs), the performance improves dramatically. The operations take almost no time.

Comment: What database are you using? What do your relation definitions look like in your model? Have you tried running [EXPLAIN](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#running-explain) on the queries and/or looked at the logs (usually containing raw SQL and timing information) to see what's making them so slow?

Comment: @Ari, please see my additional edit.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to analyze your query, there is no magic formula, but evaluate the usage of "include vs join". Usually with associations, the data is not loaded unless required.

The railscast below provide excellent idea on this, 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins

Eager loading might help prevent round trips to DB and may give better performance.